# arrow operator and boost multiarray iterator

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multi-array

Is the arrow operator missing from boost multiarray iterators? Am I wrong to expect this to work?

```
#include <vector>
#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>

struct foo {
    int n;
};

int main()
{
    {
        std::vector<foo> a;
        auto it = a.begin();
        int test = it->n; // this does compile
    }

    {
        boost::multi_array<foo, 1> a;
        auto it = a.begin();
        int test = it->n; // this does not compile
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What kind of compilation error occurs?

Comment: `'->': pointer to reference is illegal` in boost\multi_array\iterator.hpp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a bug. `array_iterator::operator->` returns a:

```
// reference here is foo&
operator_arrow_proxy<reference> operator->() const;
```

Where:

```
template <class T>
struct operator_arrow_proxy
{
  operator_arrow_proxy(T const& px) : value_(px) {}
  T* operator->() const { return &value_; }
  // This function is needed for MWCW and BCC, which won't call operator->
  // again automatically per 13.3.1.2 para 8
  operator T*() const { return &value_; }
  mutable T value_;
};
```

But `T*` here would be `foo&*` and you can't take a pointer to a reference. Moreover you cannot have a `mutable` reference member. So this whole class template is just broken for this use case.

Comment: shucks. could this be easily fixed?

Comment: @cambunctious I assume yes.

Comment: @cambunctious The `arrow_proxy` hack could work, the problem is that Multidimensional arrays need to implement things generically for any dimension (or make 1D a special case which defeats the purpose of being dimension-generic). Implementing `->` in any dimension is possible but extremely difficult in my experience, it took me a while to make it work in my library, see here https://godbolt.org/z/zGe5Kcar4 . If for generic programming reasons you really need `operator->()` to work you can try my library.